# Disabling logs when running Scrapy as script

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy in a script of mine as describe in the [Common Practices on the docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html)

I need to disable the Scrapy logs completely (not change verbosity). I tried this:

```
Spider.custom_settings['LOG_ENABLED'] = False
```

and this:

```
configure_logging({'LOG_ENABLED': False})
```

In both cases, Scrapy is still logging everything.

How do you completely disable Scapy logs when running Scrapy in a script (note that I have my own logger that I want to keep, it's just Scrapy logs that I want to remove).

Comment: Are they using python`s default logging library?

Comment: @YannicHamann I believe so yes.

Comment: There are 3 separate examples showing how to do that, and you're trying to modify them, so it's hard to know what is going on. Showing the exact code you've tried would help us help you.

Comment: What is the reason you want to completely disable logging? Another thing you can try is to redirect logs to /dev/null so nothing gets printed/saved. `nohup scrapy crawl spider >& /dev/null &`

Comment: @stranac I'm running Scrapy from a script, as the link I showed. As far as I could tall all the examples you're talking about are for running scrapy the "normal" way as a CLI scanner.

Comment: Actually, all of the python examples on that page are for running python from a script, the first 3 for a single spider, and the others for multiple ones.

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve this by using:

```
logging.getLogger('scrapy').propagate = False
```

Comment: Where did you save this line of code?  Which file?  I need to turn off logging in scrapy.

Comment: @rom I've put it right before "_process = CrawlerProcess..._" line in the script. This is the only working solution to disable logs I've found so far.

Comment: thanks you for ending a 1h pulling of hair exercise!